# how to add generic list as a value into dictionary<string,List<Restaurant>> in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
public static void InitialiseRestaurantList(Dictionary<string, List<Restaurant>> allRestaurants)
        {
            var restaurants = new List<Restaurant>();

            using (var sr = new StreamReader(@".\Restaurants.csv"))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    var line = sr.ReadLine();
                    var fields = line.Split(',');

                    var obj = new Restaurant(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3], fields[4]);
                    restaurants.Add(obj);
                }               
                sr.Close();
            }

            List<Restaurant> PuneList = new List<Restaurant>();
            foreach (Restaurant r in restaurants)
            {
                if (r.City.CompareTo("Pune")==0)
                {
                    PuneList.Add(r);
                }
            }

            Dictionary<string, List<Restaurant>> newDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Restaurant>();
            **// How to add the PuneList as a value to this newDict...?**     
      }
```

`Restaurant.csv` has the following data into it :

```
1,Mc Donald's,Pune,Kothrud,Near Karve Statue-29 
2,Dominoes,Pune,Baner,Sappehire Chamber Pune-45 
3,Faaso's,Pune,Kothrud,Karishma Society Karve Road Pune-29 
4,Pizza Hut,Nagpur,Dharampeth,Laxmibhawan Square Nagpur-10 
5,KFC,Nagpur,Ram Nagar,Near Nagpur University Nagpur-10 
6,MainLand China,Nagpur,Azim Nagar,Near Guru Nanak College of Pharmacy Nagpur-10 
7,Barbeque Nation,Goa,Margao,Near Majorda Beach Goa-01 
8,Sigree,Goa,Mapusa,Near Vagator Beach Goa-07 
9,Marakesh,Hyderabad,CBI Colony,Jubilee Hills Hyderabad-33 
10,Yana's,Hyderabad,Secundarabad,Near Mallanna Temple Hyderabad-03
```

I have taken values from csv file into a generic List of Restaurant type with 5 fields into a list, now I want to take a City as key from a list and remaining fields of the list as value, and I want to pass this as parameters to the Dictionary. Can any one help me doing so. I am able to make the separate list of restaurant by distict city. How to pass generic list as a value to dictionary.

Comment: `newDict.Add("Pune", PuneList);` ???

Comment: Also consider using `r.City == "Pune"`, if you are looking for culture insensitive comparison then look for string.Equals overload.

Comment: Have you tried to look at the list of methods for the Dictionary<string, List<Restaurant>> ? How about Add ?

Comment: Either use `Add` or even `newDict["Pune"] = PuneList`. This is all in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx), including examples.

Comment: I don't think the question is how to add the list to a dictionary, but rather how to create a dictionary out of the List, with cities as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the initializer syntax to add items to the dictionary when you declare it:

```
var newDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Restaurant>() {{"Pune", PuneList }};
```

However, I believe the last 10 lines or so of code can be simplified with some LINQ:

```
var newDict = restaurants.Where(r => r.City.CompareTo("Pune") == 0)
                         .GroupBy(r => r.City)
                         .ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.ToList());
```

**Edit**

Once you've loaded up all your restaurants into the List, you can project them into a `Dictionary`, keyed by the City name, and then you can use the dictionary to seek based on the key (City) and iterate the restaurants (I've simplified your `Restaurant`):

```
 var restaurants = new List<Restaurant>
    {
       new Restaurant("Pune", "Mc Donald's", "Pune Address #1"),
       new Restaurant("Pune", "Dominoes", "Pune Address #2"),
       new Restaurant("Nagpur", "Pizza Hut", "Nagpur Address #1")
    };
 var newDict = restaurants.GroupBy(r => r.City)
                          .ToDictionary(r => r.Key, r => r.ToList());

 foreach (var restaurant in newDict["Pune"])
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("City {0}, Address {1}, Brand {2}", restaurant.City, 
                    restaurant.Address, restaurant.Brand);
 }
```

Output:

```
City Pune, Address Pune Address #1, Brand Mc Donald's
City Pune, Address Pune Address #2, Brand Dominoes
```

Comment: Your code shows the result as : <br> <br> PuneOdeToFood.RestaurantOdeToFood.Restaurant

Comment: Can you please tell me that how to Display this Dictionary??

Comment: I've updated - since you have all the restaurants, you may as well `ToDictionary` all of them.

Comment: Thank you sir, Thanking you very much... It Working according to my need... :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply add it to the dictionary using "Add".

```
newDict.Add("Pune", PuneList);
```

You can then access it via:

```
var puneList = newDict["Pune"];
```

If you want to check weather the dictionary contains the key use:

```
bool hasPune = newDict.ContainsKey("Pune");
```

Read more about generic dictionaries [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).